# htaccess redirect issue due to php version upgradation

Tags: .htaccess, php-5.5

I have uploaded the PHP version from 5.3 to 5.5 for my website but it redirects to coming-soon page which I set for 401, 403, 500.

It works on old PHP version(5.3)

http://www.techmodi.com/demo/jaspee/services/getCMS?id=1

but It does not work for upgraded version i.e. 5.5

http://apis.jaspee.com/services/getCMS?id=1

I have also tried with AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php  but id downloads the file instead of executing.

can you please suggest the solution for the same?

## root folder .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

# Remove below Hash comment when your porject is going live (This is for PHP 5 support)

#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php



Options -Indexes

#Base navigational rules



DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^index.php|index.html|default.php|default.html$   index.php [QSA,L]



#RewriteRule ^index.php$   controller/home/home.php [QSA,L]



#Admin interface URL

RewriteRule ^admin/{0,1}$  admin/index.php [QSA,L]



#User interface URLs

RewriteRule ^aboutus[/]{0,1}$ controller/cms/cms.php?id1=1



RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/{0,1}$  panel.php?id1=$2



# Folder name($1) / File name($1) (Use this when your folder name and file name is same)

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/{0,1}$   controller/$1/$1.php



#Folder name($1) / File name($2)

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/{0,1}$      controller/$1/$2.php



#Folder name($1) / First Parameter($2) / File name($3)

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/{0,1}$  controller/$1/$3.php?id1=$2



#Folder name($1) / First Parameter($2) / Second Parameter($3) / File name($4)

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/{0,1}$    controller/$1/$4.php?id1=$2&id2=$3



#Folder name($1) / First Parameter($2) / Second Parameter($3) / Third Parameter($4) / File name($5)

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/{0,1}$    controller/$1/$5.php?id1=$2&id2=$3&id3=$4



#Folder name($1) / First Parameter($2) / Second Parameter($3) / Third Parameter($4) / Fourth Parameter($5) / File name($6)

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/{0,1}$   controller/$1/$6.php?id1=$2&id2=$3&id3=$4&id4=$5



#Folder name($1) / File name($2)

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+).html    controller/$1/$2.php

# Module htaccess end



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule .+ - [L]



# Page not found



ErrorDocument 400 http://apis.jaspee.com/comingsoon.php

ErrorDocument 401 http://apis.jaspee.com/comingsoon.php

ErrorDocument 403 http://apis.jaspee.com/comingsoon.php

ErrorDocument 404 http://apis.jaspee.com/404.php

ErrorDocument 500 http://apis.jaspee.com/comingsoon.php



</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>

mod_gzip_on Yes

mod_gzip_dechunk Yes

mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$

mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$

mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*

mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*

mod_gzip_item_include mime ^images/.*

mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*

</ifModule>

#   Check String    ([A-Za-z]+)

#   Check Number    ([0-9]+)

#   MIX     ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
```

## web service .htaccess folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# RewriteBase /jspee

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ srvcRest.php?rqst=$1 [QSA,NC,L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ srvcRest.php [QSA,NC,L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ srvcRest.php [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>


<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>

Allow from all

</Limit>
```

Comment: can anyone suggest the solution?

Comment: Can you share the contents of this .htaccess? We cannot gues what you have written there.

Comment: I have two .htaccess, in a root folder it is for mobile app admin(in web) access & another in service folder which hits webservice for mobile app.

I cannot paste the code as character limit? how can I attach the file here?

Comment: I have edited my question for more clarification..

Comment: is there any solution for the same?